# Laravel; Seeding to different tables based on value in another table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

The process I'm trying to achieve is:

- Entry1 and Entry2 go in to table A
- Entry1 and Entry2 go in to table B which shows the relation between table A and table C
- Entry1 has relation1 to table C (defined in table B), so is also placed in table D
- Entry2 has relation2 to table C (defined in table B), so is also placed in table E

So I've done the first 2 steps there, but I can't figure out how to then put entries in to a table based on their value in another table(which was just entered in to itself). I've been looking at the Query Relations section of Laravel, but I can't figure it out. Does anyone know how I can go about this?

Edit: I completely reformatted the question, hopefully it's clear, let me know if there's any of my code you'd like to see. Thanks.

Comment: You can use laravel factory to achieve such seeding, look at this https://laraveldaily.com/laravel-two-ways-seed-data-relationships/

Comment: Thanks, that link's really useful, and I think I'll definitely be using that now, but I don't see there how I could also place a contact related to ContactCompany[1] in a separate table to a contact related to ContactCompany[2]